# ProgressBar with percentage read out

Tags: c#

I tried to put a `label1.text = progressbar1.value.ToString();` and it would not read out how much it has progressed.  This is what I have so far with some help.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            progressBar1.Value = s_Checks * (progressBar1.Maximum / TOTAL_CHECKBOXES);

            label1.Text = progressBar1.Value.ToString();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private const Int32 TOTAL_CHECKBOXES = 4;

        private static Int32 s_Checks = 0;

        private void OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (((CheckBox)sender).Checked)
                ++s_Checks;
            else
                --s_Checks;

            progressBar1.Value = s_Checks * (progressBar1.Maximum / TOTAL_CHECKBOXES);
        }

        private void progressBar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (((CheckBox)sender).Checked)
                ++s_Checks;
            else
                --s_Checks;

            progressBar1.Value = s_Checks * (progressBar1.Maximum / TOTAL_CHECKBOXES);
        }

        private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (((CheckBox)sender).Checked)
                ++s_Checks;
            else
                --s_Checks;

            progressBar1.Value = s_Checks * (progressBar1.Maximum / TOTAL_CHECKBOXES);
        }

        private void checkBox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (((CheckBox)sender).Checked)
                ++s_Checks;
            else
                --s_Checks;

            progressBar1.Value = s_Checks * (progressBar1.Maximum / TOTAL_CHECKBOXES);
        }

        private void checkBox4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (((CheckBox)sender).Checked)
                ++s_Checks;
            else
                --s_Checks;

            progressBar1.Value = s_Checks * (progressBar1.Maximum / TOTAL_CHECKBOXES);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked || checkBox2.Checked || checkBox3.Checked || checkBox4.Checked == true)
            {
                checkBox1.Checked = false;
                checkBox2.Checked = false;
                checkBox3.Checked = false;
                checkBox4.Checked = false;
            }
        }

        private void clearCheckBoxToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked || checkBox2.Checked || checkBox3.Checked || checkBox4.Checked == true)
            {
                checkBox1.Checked = false;
                checkBox2.Checked = false;
                checkBox3.Checked = false;
                checkBox4.Checked = false;
            }
        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close(); 
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = progressBar1.Value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a property instead of a variable for s_Checks.  In the setter, update both the progress bar and the label.  Don't make it static, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Is the `Timer` running and `Enabled` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    progressBar1.Value = s_Checks * (progressBar1.Maximum / TOTAL_CHECKBOXES);
    label1.Text = progressBar1.Value.ToString();

    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    timer1.Interval = 1000;
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    timer1.Start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot.  Still trying to get the hang of it little bit by little bit.